# Passing FromControl in a lookup override method

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to update a form in AX to use a complex drop down box.  To do this, I need to override the Lookup method.  According to the code example I have, code like this should work:

```
public void lookup(FormControl _formControl){}
```

Unfortunately, I receive the compile error "The method override has an incorrect number of parameters."  From what I can tell, this error makes no sense as this is a valid override of the method.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lookup method on a datasource field on a form should be defined as:

```
public void lookup(FormControl _formControl, str _filterStr) {}
```

The lookup method on a control on a form should be defined as:

```
public void lookup() {}
```

In the AOT, if you right click on the Methods node where you want the function created and select Override method/lookup, AX will create a method with the correct signature for you.